# Spark: load or select Hive table of ORC format

Tags: apache-spark, exception, hive, orc, select-query

I'm trying to load a managed hive table created in ORC format with spark sql.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(ConnectionTest.class.getName()).setMaster(master);
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

SQLContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(context);

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM schema.tableName").show(20);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1021)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$HadoopMapPartitionsWithSplitRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:311)
    at com.daimler.dbdp.spark.ConnectionTest.run(ConnectionTest.java:45)
    at com.daimler.dbdp.spark.ConnectionTest.main(ConnectionTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$BISplitStrategy.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:560)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1010)
        ... 49 more
```

Seems to be something related to ORC format.
What is the best way to access hive tables when ORC format is used?

thanks!!!

spark 1.6.2.
java 8
hortonworks dist.

Comment: Did you try `sqlContext.table("schema.tableName").show()`

Comment: just did it. But bad luck. Thanks anyway

Comment: I faced exactly same issues. The table is designed with transactional=true property. I made it to false, and this error gone. But, i would prefer to use true.

Comment: Pplease do let us know workaround to solve this. I am also facing same issue. This issue is mostly with **ORC tables**, with **transactional=true**. Any solution will be helpful. Thanks.
Also do let me know what are the other allowed formats of table which supports transactions or acid operations on hive table.

Answer (score 2):

you can try setting following parameter in spark

```
scala> sql("set spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=true") 
// output = res3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, value: string]
```

Then execute the query on ORC table in spark.

If after setting above parameter also you face the issue, you can try setting following param.

```
scala> sql("set spark.sql.orc.impl=native")
// output = res4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, value: string]
```